# Error in Django to show the sender's email

Tags: django, email, sendmail

I am trying to view the sender's email that is being sent to the email host. I am able to send emails to the email_host_user using environment variables and have allowed access for less secure apps in Yahoo account. However, when I do the "from_email" I received an error: SMTPSenderRefused--(550, b'Request failed; Mailbox unavailable', 'bill@yahoo.com')--'bill@yahoo.com is just a random sender's email though I am not able to send to the email_host. I think there must be some issues with my views.py? I appreciate your feedback!

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER=os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

print(os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER'))
print(os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'))
print(os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY'))
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        message=request.POST.get('message', '')
        from_email=request.POST.get('from_email', '')

        send_mail('Contact Form', 
        message,
        from_email,
        [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
        fail_silently=False
        )

    return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
```

contact.html

```
<form action="/contact" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="email" name="from_email" placeholder="Your email">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message...">

            </textarea>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo won't allow you to send email from an unauthorized email. You can only use your `EMAIL_HOST_USER` email address to send emails.

What you can do is set `EMAIL_HOST_USER` as sender and add a `Reply-To` header with the email address provided through the form.

You should use `EmailMessage` for this

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        message=request.POST.get('message', '')
        from_email=request.POST.get('from_email', '')

        email = EmailMessage(
            subject='Contact Form',
            message=message,
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            recipient_list=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER'],
            reply_to=[from_email]
        )
        email.send(fail_silently=False)


    return render(request, 'first_app/contact.html')
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

Comment: Thank you Aman for the thorough feedback. I edited: ```
        

        email = EmailMessage(
            subject='Contact Form',
            body=message,
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            to=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],
            reply_to=['from_email']
        )
        email.send(fail_silently=False)``` Email was able to be sent--although when I click "Reply" it shows "To: from_email" and Yahoo states to correct the email address

Comment: Actually, nvm--the [from_email] had to be a variable, not string as you advised. It works! Do you think this may be an issue since my email host, password and secret key are in environment variables to be deployed in AWS? Or do I  need to do any additional edits in the settings during deployment?

Comment: `from_email` is the variable..look closely.

Comment: You can keep the settings as environment variables, or you can keep them in a separate file which no one can access.